# Efficiency / overhead of EventSource vs polled ajax? 

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, comet, polling

I am writing a simple app that's very similar to a chat application in terms of its use.  A host starts a "room", participants can join and send messages into said room.

I am trying to make this as simple as possible to code.  PHP on the backend without anything fancy.

My first thought was to just do polled ajax from the clients to see if a new message is posted in the room. Then I thought this causes a crazy amount of requests to the server (granted they're tiny, but still).

Then I looked into more HTML5 ways of doing it and found EventSource - this seems right in theory but I wonder it under the covers it's just polled ajax anyway.

Then there's comet but it also requires a server side component that I'm not too eager to set up.

I guess I can use long polling - is that the best approach?

Also, how do you minimize db requests from all the clients asking for new data?

Answer (score 4):

I think that short polling is the simplest to code, but it may create unnecessary load on the server.

Long polling is more efficient, but you have to have a server that is able to efficiently support many-many connections (that is, not Apache).

And yes, EventSource is just a glorified long-polling, but it's pleasant to work with.

Answering to your second question: the best way to minimize number of db request is to not make db requests. Put things into memcached, for example.

Comment: but EventSource polls every 3 seconds by default. i know you can alter that time but I thought the idea with long polling is that you set up one request and it just waits till there's data - how do you do that with eventsource?

Comment: No, EventSource tries to *reconnect* each 3 seconds. If you don't close the connection, it will get updates right away.

Comment: you mean continuously as they become available?  are there any downsides to not closing that connection?

Comment: @MichaelDrob: of course there are. You have to keep the connection open! :-) Most servers are simply not designed for this. In most cases it makes sense to use Apache for serving your pages and something like Node.js to handle long-polling.

Comment: i'm running on dreamhost so i dont think node js is an option - also, it raises complexity for me

Comment: If your chat isn't going to be popular then use short polling and be happy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sergio has provided a good answer to the EventSource question. He's also states that Apache won't scale to handle many-many simultaneous/concurrent connections. PHP on Apache has this problem - especially if you are using shared hosting.

The best solution for PHP is to outsource the realtime web communications and the distribution of the messages. You can do this yourself by using a [self hosted realtime web solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted)...

> > Then there's comet but it also requires a server side component that I'm not too eager to set up.

But it sounds like your not to keen to set that up. So, your best option is a hosted realtime web solution such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) which uses WebSockets. By using such a service you would implement your chat app as follows:

- When a user joins a room they subscribe to a `chat-channel`. The name can be specific to the topic of conversation e.g. `chat-fishing` (more info on channels [here](http://pusher.com/docs/channels))
- When a user submits a chat message your server would receive that message (probably via an AJAX request)
- You would update your database with this new message
- Once the DB has successfully updated you can then distribute (broadcast) that message to every user within the same chat room by triggering a `new_message` event on the `chat-channel` channel. This is done via the hosted service RESTful API using a [PHP library](https://github.com/squeeks/Pusher-PHP) (which wraps up any functionality like authentication required by the RESTful API).
- The message is received by the connected clients.

The [tech example in this presentation](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/pusher/pusher-presentations/why_use_pusher.html#8) should demonstrate the benefits of oursourcing the distribution of messages.

There's a good tutorial about [how to build a chat application using PHP with Pusher on Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-real-time-with-pusher/).

Although this solution/answer is very Pusher-centric the concepts (outsourcing benefits, subscriptions, channels and events) are applicable to all [realtime hosted services](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services) that support realtime client push.

Comment: interesting solution. i'm looking to do this for free, at least for the near future - or rather not more than what i'm paying for hosting now and I dont think DH does any sort of realtime hosting... good to know about this stuff though - thanks!